# deviceready not fired - onFileSystemPathsReady

Tags: cordova, android-studio, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating a Cordova / Phonegap application and I am getting this issue occasionally and randomly

```
"deviceready not fired after 5 seconds. 
Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady"
```

My Cordova application is a Multi Page App (not a SPA).

I am using Cordova **5.4.1** with (Android Build **4.1.1**)

I am using file plugin of version **4.3.0**. (and also tried plugin version 3.0 and 4.2.0)

Issue comes mostly in devices with **Android version 6.0.1**.

I am using **Android studio 2.1.1** with **Java 1.8.0_101** (earlier was using 2.2 and 2.3)

I have kept the **Gradle Instant Run off**.

Mostly the issue comes when I move from one page to another i.e. when I call **window.location.href**

My Code:

```
/* It's working fine on the index.html page */
/* Index.html demo page (actual page has many css and js files) */
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/core/pages/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="startExecution()">

  </body>
</html>


/* index.js page */

var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();

document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady, false);

function deviceReady() {

  if (navigator) {
    if (navigator.splashscreen) {
      navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }

  }

  // after some processing or API hit
  window.location.href = "page1.html";
}

function startExecution() {
  d2.resolve();
}


$.when(d1, d2).done(function () {
  console.log('Both resolved');

  window.location.href = "page2.html";
});
```

The problem comes when I go to page1.html 
on page1 too I have attached the necessary files like cordova.js.
But occasionally I get the above error:
**"deviceready not fired after 5 seconds.
 Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady"**

It used to work properly, but somehow suddenly I started getting this error. I don't understand why, please help me out.

Comment: Any updates? I got the same thing. Is there a chance you were doing anything with either localStorage or sessionStorage?